# How to render input inside label - using zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

As title says, how can i generate a form using zend form having input inside label?
Something like

```
<label class="checkbox" for="persistent">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="persistent" data-toggle="checkbox">
    Remember Me
</label>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can likely add a decorator to your input field.

Comment: Found it. Thanks!
Method used:
1. extended zend form decorator
2. edited element

More info here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.form.decorators.layering.html